# Count the number of times post has been viewed

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a project where only title of posts are shown on main page and on clicking the title, full post is loaded on another page `posts.php` code for this is:

```
<a href="posts.php?postId=<?php echo $row['posts_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

Now to count post views I have a column `hits` in my `posts` table ,initially value of `hits` is set to `0` and whenever a post is opened value of `hits` is increased by 1, for this my code is in `posts.php`

```
$id = $_GET['postId'];
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE post_id = $id";
```

But this is not a good practice for tracking post views as views increase whenever page is refreshed. I want a clean system to track post views where, for every distinct user or visitor views increase by one irrespective of fact how many times the same user/visitor views same post (as in stackoverflow). Like tracking them by their IP address or something else, just an idea (how these guys do it) or how the stuff works would be enough to let me start my work.

Comment: i'd create a new table for the count where there is `post_id` and the `IP` address of the viewer.  Then base the updating of the `hits` on that table.

Comment: You need to do some reading up on [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your example code is wide open to it.

Comment: @vascowhite thanks ,which one you are talking about  first or second piece of code,,,for the first I can't find a better way to pass variable and If you are talking about second line I am deleting that code as I mentioned it's not productive

Comment: Please don't use IP for this task! It's better if you will use MAC Address. As you may know, in the companies even 100 persons may have the same IP (all of them linked to each other over local network, and to Internet over router). But MAC Address is always unique

Comment: @Khazratbek he isn't able to determine the MAC address. As may obviously don't know, when, in companies, people share the same IP, they sit behind a router that is [NATing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT). A peer will only see the router's MAC (and even this might not be the case if there are other routers or proxies involved).

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot solve your problem so simply.  Your problem is counting unique users who view a page (with, perhaps a time component).  You have several problems, as described in the comments.  The first is determining what you are counting.  For a prototype, IP address is good as anything else for getting started.  However, it has many short-comings, and you will need to think hard about identifying a "visitor".

There is a way to solve your problem in SQL, sort of efficiently.  But, it requires an additional table at the level of post/visitor.  It will have one row per combination, and then you will need to count from there.  To quickly get the unique counts, you then need an insert trigger on that table.

Here is a sketch of the code:

```
create unique index unq_postvisitors_post_visitor on postvisitors(postid, visitorid);

insert into PostVisitors (postid, visitorid)
    select $postid, $visitorid
    on duplicate key update set counter = counter + 1;

delimiter $$
create trigger trig_PostVisitors
    after insert on PostVisitors
begin
    update posts
        set numvisitors = numvisitors + 1
        where posts.post_id = new.post_id;
end;$$

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I use to solve this problem is through cookies.

Whenever your page is opened, you check if there's set `cookie_name` cookie through `isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])`.

If isset returns false, you set a cookie through `setcookie(cookie_name, value, expire);`, maybe setting expire time to 24h (you have to set it in seconds, so 24h is 84600). Also, you trigger your counting systems with a +1 to your visitor counter.

If isset returns true, do nothing.

[PHP Cookies Refs](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this It'll Work

```
$refreshed = $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'];
if ($refreshed == 'max-age=0'){
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE post_id = $id"; 
}
```

Try this script on the page `$_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']` get place when page is refreshed